# How to show in Play Store that the app is an internal beta release?

Tags: android

I have set up a group on Play Console for internal beta testing and invited about 30 people. We got a beta link from Google to share but it's identical to the normal Play Store URL.

When the user opens this page, it will give no indication that this is actually a new app. It still shows the old icon, update date and screenshots.

How can I change this? So there is a visual cue that you are installing a new beta version?

Answer (score 0):

The link for the app will be identical since it is the same package name.

If they have accepted the beta channel invitation AND your beta build that you uploaded to the beta channel will have a different icon, it will be different.

With that said you would have to always have beta versionCode higher than that of the production channel.

Comment: So it's 'closed testing' but the users do not receive an invite. They see the old app in the store, but when they install it, it will be the newer beta version. This causes lots of confusion. You say they have to accept the invite. How do they do that? They don't get any email.